# How to abort wget after n times

Tags: php, linux, unix, cron, wget

I am checking if a website is online or offline. If offline, this cron task call an url to text me a message.

Here is my cron job :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget "www.mydomain.fr" --timeout 30 -O - 2>/dev/null | grep "a_string_in_the_site" || echo "The site is offline" | wget "urltotextmeamessage.com"
```

This task check every 30 seconds the site status, and send a message if the site is offline : OKAY

The problem is that I don't want hundred of messages every 30 seconds when the site will be offline.

Is it possible to stop the cron task after n times (or to make a "break") till the moment the site will be online again?

Any idea ?

Comment: try to apply condition on crone job. http://serverfault.com/questions/661139/if-condition-is-true-sleep-the-cron-job-for-5-minutes

Comment: Write a script that make the job...

Answer (score 0):

I would not stop the cron job, because you still have to check
if the server is online again. You could limit the msgs to 
OK/DOWN msgs with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#   /usr/local/sbin/check_webserver

wget -O - -q "checkurl" | if grep -q "checkword"; then
    echo "Server OK" > /var/run/check_webserver
else
    echo "Server DOWN" > /var/run/check_webserver
fi

diff -q /var/run/check_webserver /var/run/check_webserver.old >/dev/null  2>&1 || 
cat /var/run/check_webserver
# or put some other msg service than cron mail here

cp /var/run/check_webserver /var/run/check_webserver.old
```

and add this to cron:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/sbin/check_webserver
```